# Angular 5: Shopping cart

Tags: angular

I'd like implement in my app service for shopping cart.I have a problem with creating items in new cart. When I want to assing a new creating cart to a product taken from my service, I have an error :

> Type 'Observable' is missing the following properties from type 'Products': Id, Name, Description, DetailedDescription, and 5 more.

in the line `Product: this.productService.getProductById(id),` And second error:

> Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'number'

in the line: `TotalPrice: this.productService.getProductById(id).map(data => data.Price)`

**CartItem class:**

```
export class CartItem {
 product: Products;
 quantity: number;
 totalPrice: number;
}
```

**Service:**

```
 getProductById(id) {
return this.http.get<Products>('http://localhost:61085/api/Products/GetProductsById/' + id);}
```

**CartComponent:**

```
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {

  private items: CartItem[] = [];
  constructor(private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute , private productService: CategoriesProductsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addProductToCart();
  }

  addProductToCart() {
    this.activeRoute.params.subscribe( params => {
      let id = +params['id'];
      if (id) {

        let item: CartItem = {
              Product: this.productService.getProductById(id), // <-- error
              Quantity: 1,
              TotalPrice: this.productService.getProductById(id).map(data => data.Price)  // <-- error
        };
          // if the cart is empty, set localstorage
        if (localStorage.getItem('userCart') === null) {
          let cart = [];
          cart.push(JSON.stringify(item));
          localStorage.setItem('userCart', JSON.stringify(cart));
        } else {
          // if the cart exist 
          let cart: any = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userCart'));
          let index = -1;
          for (let i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
              let item: CartItem = JSON.parse(cart[i]);
              if (item.Product.Id === id) {
                  index = i;
                  break;
              }
          }
          if (index === -1) {
                cart.push(JSON.stringify(item));
                localStorage.setItem('userCart', JSON.stringify(cart));
          } else {
              let item: CartItem = JSON.parse(cart[index]);
              item.Quantity++;
              cart[index] = JSON.stringify(item);
              localStorage.setItem('userCart', JSON.stringify(cart));
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
  loadCart() {
    this.items = [];
    let cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userCart'));
    for (let i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
      let item = JSON.parse(cart[i]);
      this.items.push({
        Product: item.Product,
        Quantity: item.Quantity,
        TotalPrice: item.Product.Price
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<h2> Cart info</h2>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let product of items">
    <p>{{product.Product.Name}}</p>
    <p>{{product.Quantity}}</p>
    <p>Total price: {{product.TotalPrice * product.Product.Price}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help or suggestion is welcome

Comment: Well you are trying to assign observables to your properties, which will of course throw an error, since your class is defined otherwise. You need to **subscribe** to your observables and assign **those** values.

Answer (score 0):

It’s a lengthy question. Anyway below is the answers.

1. We can’t comment on it until we get the implementation of Products. In the preliminary view, it’s because of you are trying to assign an `Observable` data type to `Products` data type. Because, you are assigning a value to product by calling the below line

   Product: this.productService.getProductById(id)

This function return type Observable and the Products is not. You can rectify this by just altering your code to

```
this.productService.getProductById(id)
.subscribe((data)=>{this.Products = data;});
```

2. The getProductById is not returning an number data type. As mentioned above it’s `Observable` .

So as we did above it’s could be rectified as similar as

```
this.productService.getProductById(id)
.subscribe((data )=> {this.TotalPrice = data.Price;});
```

Please let’s know if this is not rectified your case.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what problem you have facing, am giving general solution.

First import Observable in your service.ts

```
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

After that add observer to your function.

```
getProductById(id):Observable<Product> {
return this.http.get('http://localhost:61085/api/Products/GetProductsById/' + id);}
```